# Overriding with !important code in CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, overriding

Currently, the CSS stylesheet for my blog has most of the elements in my blog (body, a, headers, etc.) set to a certain font and size. I went ahead and set a different font family and font size for specific elements, such as the entry content title and the sidebar widget titles using the !important code to override the main blog font and size. Doing this worked just fine for both these situations until this morning, when suddenly the sidebar widget titles completely changed. It's odd because I've been refreshing my cache continuously so I know that it's not an old CSS change that is suddenly appearing now. Anyway, what it seems to be doing is using the header font (h1) that I had set, which is "Didot" font size 22px (the same settings used for the entry content title), however, I have specified that the .widget h1 be set to font size 14 !important, with borders on the top and bottom. The !important used to override no longer seems to be working as the font size is still 22, and the top and bottom borders that had been set for .widget h1, which were previously visible, are no longer showing.

Does anyone know how I can remedy this? Here is my blog link: http://MissSophisticate.com

Comment: woo...thats a lot of "important", should read about "specificity"  http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ and http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: You should avoid !important unless you know explicitly you need it, and in this case, I can tell you that you don't need it.  You can override the styles by making sure you select the element with the same specificity as the styles you are wanting to override.  So long as you have setup a proper child theme for the site, then it should overwrite just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm a complete newbie with this css stuff so I'm having trouble even understanding the specificity articles you have linked. I'm not sure which is the class or which is the id. I just know that in terms of order, the headers (h1-h6) have been set...and then the .widget has been set, and then there's the specific widget title I'm dealing with which is .widget h1

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using !important unless it is absolutely necessary as once you start using it in a few places things can get complicated quickly!

Rather than !important you should use CSS's specificity and inheritance rules to override specific styles, this means the ordering of the styles in the stylesheet and how specific the selector is, once you get into the habit of doing this you should find that you never need to use !important

And to answer your specific problem...

It looks like you have added some HTML into your stylesheet by mistake, look at line 78....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Removing this should help!